# only need next button which would lead to next and previous blogs

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, blogs

I am using wordpress.i have created blogs.here i am displaying previous and next links using

```
<div id="bottom_prev">
<?php previous_posts_link('Previous') ?>
</div>
<div id="bottom_next">
<?php next_posts_link('Next') ?>
</div>
```

But i don't want previous only i need next.I like the link "next" which would lead to the previous and next blogs.that means next button needs to work in circular way

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you -

```
<?php 
if( get_next_posts_link() ) 
{ 
next_posts_link('next'); 
} 
else 
{ 
echo '<a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" title="home again">back to beginning</a>'; } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set condition

```
<?php 
if( get_next_posts_link() ) 
{ 
next_posts_link('next'); 
} 
else 
{ 
echo '<a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" title="home again">back to beginning</a>'; } 
?>
```